Why does the warning about Timestamps for Activities and Cases point to DoctorWhen?
A new warning on the system status pages gives notice that new timestamp fields have been added and we might want to populate them. That's all fine, but why does the text point to the doctorwhen page? I don't see anything there about this issue, in fact there's been no recent activity there at all. I'm not sure what doctorwhen has to do with these new fields.
Timestamps for Activities and Cases
The tables "civicrm_activity" and "civicrm_case" were updated to support two new fields, "created_date" and "modified_date". For historical data, these fields may appear blank. (11779 records have NULL timestamps.)
At time of writing, this is not a problem. However, future extensions and improvements could rely on these fields, so it may be useful to back-fill them.
For further discussion, please visit https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.doctorwhen

This might ultimately be the same as your other question since it's part of the civicase system status checks. Something is going wrong with how it detects civicase.

Huh. Well I'll look some more at it to see if I can identify a cause. Thanks.

There's a patch now available here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/30636/files
